# Variable either not getting passed to or from the function

Tags: php, function, variables

The point of the code is to edit a specific user which is determinded by which edit button has been pressed.

I'm getting the following error:

Undefined variable: user_id in EditUser.php on line 15.

No this in not an undefined variable issue. If I remove $user_id when calling the function it complains that the function calling has no arguments.

I only want the return of the function, but it doesn't want to get called.

EditUser.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'Functions.php';
$user = new User();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['EditUser']))
            {
                $result = User::Edit_User($user_id); //The line which gives me the error

                while(list($user_id, $username, $password, $emailadres, $admin) = mysql_fetch_array($result ))
                {
                    $urid = $user_id;
                    $urnm = $username;
                    $pw = $password;
                    $eml = $emailadres;
                    $an = $admin;
                    echo "It worked"; //Just aline for debugging. Will remove later
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error";
            }
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="EditUserDef.php">
            user_id: </br>
            <input readonly="readonly" name="user_id" value=<?php echo $urid ?>></br>
            username: </br>
            <input type="input" name="username" value=<?php echo $urnm ?>></br>
            password: </br>
            <input type="input" name="password" value=<?php echo $pw ?>></br>
            emailadres: </br>
            <input type="input" name="emailadres" value=<?php echo $eml ?>></br>
            admin: </br>
            <input type="input" name="admin" value=<?php echo $an ?>></br>
            <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="edit data">
            <input type="button" value="back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></br>
            </br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file with the class and funcitons, Functions.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'Config.php'; //Class to connect with database, not really important for this question
class User
{
    public function Edit_User($user_id) 
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if (!$rows == 0) 
        {
            $_SESSION['EditUser'] = true;
            return $query;
        }
    }
    public function Edit_DataSession() 
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['EditUser']));
    }
```

And as last, the file from where the "user_id" gets send to Functions.php, Administration.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'Functions.php';
$user= new User();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $user_id = $_POST['hidden'];
    $editing = $user->Edit_User($user_id);

    if ($editing) 
    {
        header("location:EditUser.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'User doesn't exist anymore';
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            table, td, th
            {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>overzicht gebruikers</h1>
        <table border = 1>
        <tr>
            <td>user_id</td>
            <td>username</td>
            <td>password</td>
            <td>emailadres</td>
            <td>admin</td>
        </tr>

        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['GetUser'])) //function not included in the code of the question, didn't seem necesarry
            {
                $result = user::get_user();

                while(list($user_id, $username, $password, $emailadres, $admin) = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat))
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>$user_id</td>";
                    echo "<td>$username</td>";
                    echo "<td>$password</td>";
                    echo "<td>$emailadres</td>";
                    echo "<td>$admin</td>";

                    echo "<td><form action='EditUser.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=$user_id><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></form></td>";
                    echo "<td><form action='DeleteUser.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=$user_id><input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'></form></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "this in not an undefined variable issue" - yes it is.

Comment: @rjdown how? Can you tell me where? Almost all my functions work like this, and this is the only one complaining when its being called for. Also the variable is getting send to Functions.php from Administration.php, before the function gets called in EditUser.php and causing the error. I can't see the problem.

Comment: You're simply not defining $user_id before you use it. Where are you expecting it to be set? Look there and see why it is not. I'm not seeing how Administration.php has anything to do with this.

Comment: @rjdown 

"if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $user_id = $_POST['hidden'];
    $editing = $user->Edit_User($user_id);}" it gets defined there to be used in the function.

Comment: But that line is on a different page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No this in not an undefined variable issue.

Um, yes it is.  Error messages are pretty good at telling you the error:

> Undefined variable: user_id in EditUser.php on line 15

So let's look at line 15:

```
$result = User::Edit_User($user_id);
```

You're trying to use a variable called `$user_id`.  Looking above that line, I don't see that variable *defined* anywhere.  You define a variable called `$user`:

```
$user = new User();
```

But where do you define a variable called `$user_id`?  According to your code, and according to the PHP runtime, you don't.  Hence the error.

You do define a similarly named variable on a completely different page, but variables don't persist across page contexts.  You need to re-define it with each page request where you want to use it.

You need to define variables before you can use them.  Maybe you meant to use a member of `$user` instead of `$user_id`?  Maybe you meant to use `$user` itself?  The code isn't going to be able to know what you mean, you have to explicitly define things.

Comment: $user_id is being defined in Administration.php before getting send to the function which I try to call. Do I have to define it again before caling the function? 0_0

Comment: @BadAtPHP: Variables don't persist across different page contexts.  Each request made to the server essentially starts from scratch in processing.  You'd need to define the variable again before you can use it.